# How do I fill in values in a dataframe provided meets it meets the required condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got two dataframes:

```
data1 = {"occ_1": ("a", "b", "b", "c"),"salary": (np.nan, np.nan, 20, 30)}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
data2 = {"occ_2": ("a", "b"), "avg_salary": (10,20)}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

In df1, the salary column has several null fields. I would like to replace these null fields with the average_sal of while matching the values of occ_1 and occ_2. Any help on how do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace missing values by mapped values from `df2` by `occupation_1` column:

```
s = df2.set_index('occupation_2')['average_salary']
df1['salary'] = df1['salary'].fillna(df1['occupation_1'].map(s))
```